# Select Table of Content In Word Document

Tags: c#, ms-word

Is there a way to select the table of content which is already defined in my Word document?

```
TableOfContents toc = wordDoc.TablesOfContents.Add(rangeForTOCTOF, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TablesOfContents` variable is a collection. You can access the individual ToCs by indexing into the collection, for example:

```
TableOfContents oneToC = wordDoc.TablesOfContents[1];
```

The individual ToC is documented [in the Word 2013 developer reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837673.aspx).

However that TOC is not selectable, so if you want to select a TOC you have to walk the document fields explicitly:

```
// select the first TOC
foreach (Field f in wordDoc.Fields) {
    if (f.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldTOC) {
        f.Select();
        break; 
    }
}
```

EDIT. From @bibadia, also consider,

```
TableOfContents oneToC = wordDoc.TablesOfContents[1];
oneToC.Range.Select();
```

Comment: @mockunterface, Thanks for your reply, I suggest how to get a particular ToC, I would like to select it in the document- to focus selection on it. Any ideas?

Comment: Something like wordDoc.TablesOfContents[1].Range.Select should also do it.